# jQuery datepicker - update values

Tags: jquery, datepicker

My datepicker works great but I just need to update the `a` (#daterange) tag with the selected dates whenever the "#todate" date is selected/changed:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5HQeg/

```
$(function () {

    var picker_from = $( '#fromdate' ).pickadate({
        onSelect: function() {
            var fromDate = createDateArray( this.getDate( 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) )
            picker_to.data( 'pickadate' ).setDateLimit( fromDate )
        },
        format: 'mmm dd, yyyy',
        formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
    var picker_to = $( '#todate' ).pickadate({
        onSelect: function() {
            var toDate = createDateArray( this.getDate( 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) )
            picker_from.data( 'pickadate' ).setDateLimit( toDate, 1 )
        },
        format: 'mmm dd, yyyy',
        formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
    function createDateArray( date ) {
        return date.split( '-' ).map(function( value ) { return +value })
    };

});
```

I can't find the function to do that with this datepicker plugin.

Comment: ah.. guess I assumed since he said jQuery datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write onchange function for textbox:

```
$('#todate').change(function () {
    $('.daterange').text($('#fromdate').val() + '-' + $(this).val());
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/5HQeg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how to format the dates, but to put them inside the `a` tag, here's what I did:

#### [Fiddle work](http://jsfiddle.net/5HQeg/1/embedded/result/)

1. Add some `id`s to span.

   ```
   <a href="#" class="daterange"><span id="numfrom">Dec 21, 2012 </span>-<span id="numto"> Jan 20, 2013</span></a>
   ```
2. Edit `onSelect` functions to and appended this:

   ```
   $('#numfrom').text(fromDate); // For the fromDate section
   ```

The final function becomes:

```
var picker_from = $('#fromdate').pickadate({
    onSelect: function () {
        var fromDate = createDateArray(this.getDate('yyyy-mm-dd'));
        picker_to.data('pickadate').setDateLimit(fromDate);
        $('#numfrom').text(fromDate);
    },
    format: 'mmm dd, yyyy',
    formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
var picker_to = $('#todate').pickadate({
    onSelect: function () {
        var toDate = createDateArray(this.getDate('yyyy-mm-dd'));
        picker_from.data('pickadate').setDateLimit(toDate, 1);
        $('#numto').text(toDate);
    },
    format: 'mmm dd, yyyy',
    formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
```